# How are these simulated sample means created/plotted in R?

Tags: r, simulation, density-function, kernel-smoothing, histogram

I had a student point out this image in *Learning Statistics with Jamovi* that is also in *Learning Statistics with R* (Page 294 in the latter). I was going to send her a reply when I noticed something in the image:

[image]

Here it seems the author simulated some sample means and increased the sample size until reaching normality (to basically show how CLT works). Usually the explanations in the R book come with code to emulate what has been done, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. However, I'm not entirely sure how they arrived at these plots. One can easily simulate a normal distribution with `rnorm` and of course some kind of left skew with `rbeta`, but how does one achieve this by-sample size plotting shown here?

Comment: The $n=1$ case is triangular and can be simulated by (in R)  `function(n) { 
x <- runif(n)+runif(n)
ifelse(x <= 1, x, 2-x) }`

Comment: @Kjetil: It's a Beta$(2,1)$ distribution.

Comment: The complete set can be generated and graphed as `n <- 1e5;
a <- 2; b <- 1;
X <- matrix(rbeta(n*8, a, b), 8);
par(mfrow = c(2,2));
for (k in c(1,2,4,8)) {
  hist(colMeans(X[1:k, , drop = FALSE]), freq = FALSE, ylim = c(0, 5), 
       main = paste("Sample Size =", k), xlab = "Sample Mean",
       col = hsv(.65, .33, 1),
       breaks = seq(0, 1.2, length.out = 61));
  curve(dnorm(x, a/(a+b), sqrt(a * b / (a + b + 1) / k) / (a + b)), add = TRUE, lwd = 2)
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to perform a simulation for four different sample sizes, replicating, for each sample size, the simulation hundreds or thousands of times, maybe more. This is not quite a demonstration of the central limit theorem, since the central limit theorem applies not to sample means but to $Z=\sqrt{n}\dfrac{\bar X -\mu}{\sigma}\overset{}{\rightarrow}N(0,1)$, rather than convergence of $\bar X$ itself.

Consequently, I would run the simulation like this:

```r
set.seed(2023)
Ns <- c(1, 2, 4, 8)
R <- 1000000
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
for (i in 1:length(Ns)){
  
  print(i)
  N <- Ns[i]
  xbars <- rep(NA, R)
  for (j in 1:R){
    x <- rbeta(N, 2, 1)
    xbars[j] <- mean(x)
  }
  hist(
    xbars,
    50,
    main = paste(
      "Sample Size =",
      N
    ),
    xlab = "Sample Means"
  )
}
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
```

[image: histograms]

I loop over the sample sizes so I perform the simulation at each of the four sample sizes given in the plot, so $1$, $2$, $4$, and $8$. For each sample size, I do a million iterations of drawing a sample from a $\text{Beta}(2, 1)$ distribution (which looked about right, given the source plot), and then I calculate the sample mean. After I have done this a million times, I plot a histogram of the sample means, and then I move to the next sample size.

**EDIT**

The density plot seems to be created by shoehorning into a Gaussian distribution and mean and variance of the simulated sample means.

```r
set.seed(2023)
Ns <- c(1, 2, 4, 8)
R <- 1000000
xaxis_values_for_density <- seq(0, 1, 0.001)
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
for (i in 1:length(Ns)){
  
  print(i)
  N <- Ns[i]
  xbars <- rep(NA, R)
  for (j in 1:R){
    x <- rbeta(N, 2, 1)
    xbars[j] <- mean(x)
  }
  hist(
    xbars,
    50,
    main = paste(
      "Sample Size =",
      N
    ),
    freq = F,
    xlab = "Sample Means",
    col = "lightblue"
  )
  lines(
    xaxis_values_for_density, 

    # It is in this "dnorm" line where the shoehorning takes place
    #
    dnorm(xaxis_values_for_density, mean(xbars), sd(xbars)),
    col = "black",
    lwd = 2
    )
}
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
```

[image: histograms with shoehorned Gaussian densities]

Comment: Wow this was really great. One final stupid question...basically the density plot line here is effectively the "same" density across all the values that were simulated, but the line in each plot pane is "stretched" based off which sample size is given? My intuition on this still isn't super clear.

Comment: The density plot is not the same, and that's why they're getting narrower. Each one uses a different mean and variance shoehorned into the Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Ahh I just now figured out what you mean. Thank you very much Dave.